# Solution of $Ax^5+Bx^3=C$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots

I have to find the positive solution of the type $Ax^5+Bx^3=C (A,B,C>0)$. It is well known that a polynomial of degree greater than $4$ does not admit an expression for the roots but I hope :D

In fact, I want to minimize $a_0x^{-\beta}+b_0x^{1-\beta}+c_0x$ and by Derivative it becomes $a_1x^{-\beta-1}+b_1x^{-\beta}=c_1$. Then when $\beta=1,2$ it admits a radical solution as it is simple for $\beta=1$ and it is root of polynomial of degree $3$ for $\beta=2$. Now I consider $\beta=3/2$ and it becomes $Ax^5+Bx^3=C$.

Comment: where did u find this question

Comment: @arbautjc : There is no general formula for polynomials of degree 5 and above, it is a proven theorem. Having said so, some polynomials have radical solutions (that you can write down in terms of basic operations and powers).

Comment: @Tulip : For any $A,B,C>0$ I don't think it has any expression like you want it. Perhaps there are ways of expressing the solutions but not in the way you hope.

Comment: In fact, I want to minimize $a_0x^{-\beta}+b_0x^{1-\beta}+cx$ and by Derivative it becomes $a_1x^{-\beta-1}+b_1x^{-\beta}=c_1$. Then when $\beta=1,2$ it admits a radical solution. Now I consider $\beta=3/2$ and it becomes $Ax^5+Bx^3=C$.

Comment: @arbautjc : I am not confusing, as I stated I know that there are no general formula solutions by radical (ok I forgot to mention by radical in my first sentence), that is plug in $A$, $B$ and $C$ and get the answer. I know that some specific quintics and higher polynomials can be solved using transcendental functions but I am unaware of a general formula solving all quintics using them.

Comment: @Tulip : Edit your question to include these informations.

Comment: Tulip, do you mind if I add the `galois-theory` tag to this question?  Using those methods it should be provable whether there exists a simple formula or not for the roots, but my knowledge is too rusty to do it myself.  I'm sure someone browsing that tag would be able to help.

Comment: Thx Antonio, I tag galois-theory to the question.

Answer (score 1):

For positive $x$ the left side is monotonically increasing and convex. Thus the equation is uniquely solvable. Furthermore, Newton's method is save to use if starting from some outer root radius $x_0=R$. For this example $R=\max\left(1,\sqrt[5]{\frac{C}{A+B}}\right)$ could be used.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but anyway... The general quintic can be reduced to the following trinomial forms,

$$ax^5+bx^4+c = 0\tag1$$

$$ax^5+bx^3+c = 0\tag2$$

$$ax^5+bx^2+c = 0\tag3$$

$$ax^5+bx+c = 0\tag4$$

hence yours $(2)$, in general, is not solvable in radicals.